# Hibernate session.persist() vs JPA entityManager.persist()

Tags: hibernate, jpa

From  Java Persistence with Hibernate (Manning, 2007) p. 419:

> *Should I use persist() on the Session?* The Hibernate Session interface
>   also features a persist() method. It has the same semantics as the
>   persist() operation of JPA. However, there’s an important difference
>   between the two operations with regard to flushing. During
>   synchronization, a Hibernate Session doesn’t cascade the persist()
>   operation to associated entities and collections, even if you mapped
>   an association with this option. **It’s only cascaded to entities that
>   are reachable when you call persist()!** Only save() (and update()) are
>   cascaded at flush-time if you use the Session API. In a JPA
>   application, however, it’s the other way round: Only persist()is
>   cascaded at flush-time.

Such an illegible wording... What does it mean "entities that are reachable when you call persist()"?

If I updated an associated entity then should it not be "reachable"?

Also... if it is part of the behavior of session.persist(), then why is it not in the [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: reachable = you can navigate from the object passed to persist to get to the other object. This navigation is via normal java object fields. reachable also means navigate from object A, to object B, to object C etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have sincerely no idea if this is true or not, but I can at least explain what it means.

Suppose you have the following entity:

```
public class Order {
    @OneToMany(cascade = PERSIST)
    private List<OrderLine> lines;
    // ...
}
```

and you do the following:

```
Order order = new Order();
session.persist(order);
OrderLine line = new OrderLine();
order.addLine(line);
session.flush(); // the flush could also be called implicitely, when committing or executing a query
```

According to the text in your question, the line won't be persisted, because it's not reachable from the order when `persist(order)` is called: at this time, the line is not in the order yet.

On the other hand, is you use the entity manager:

```
Order order = new Order();
em.persist(order);
OrderLine line = new OrderLine();
order.addLine(line);
em.flush(); // the flush could also be called implicitely, when committing or executing a query
```

then the line will be persisted, because it's reachable from the order at flush time, when the state of the entity is synchronized to the database.

Comment: Did you mean `order.addLine(line)`? I think you're saying this is theoretically what they might mean but you have no idea if they really do? This scenario that you are describing requires multiple snapshots per persistent object... does Hibernate actually go for that overkill?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `order.addLine()`. I don't understand what you mean by "multiple snapshots per persistent object". Each session has one and only one instance per given persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate's EntityManager implementation is:

```
org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.3.5.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final-sources.jar!\org\hibernate\jpa\spi\AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java
```

and this is the persist() method

```
@Override
public void persist(Object entity) {
    checkOpen();
    try {
        internalGetSession().persist( entity );
    }
    catch ( MappingException e ) {
        throw convert( new IllegalArgumentException( e.getMessage() ) ) ;
    }
    catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
        throw convert( e );
    }
}
```

So the JPA persist(entity) is actually calling org.hibernate.internal.Session.persist(entity).

So, there shouldn't be any difference between JPA and Hibernate when it comes to persisting entities.

> It’s only cascaded to entities that are reachable when you call
>   persist()!

In 2007 Hibernate 3.2 was already released and the 3.3 version was on the way. back then [JPA was only a draft](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent):

> You may also use persist() instead of save(), with the semantics defined in the EJB3 > > > early draft.

But according to the docs:

> If a parent is passed to persist(), all children are passed to
>   persist()

For JPA it makes sense to cascade persist(), since there is no save() operation at all. But back then people were using save(), saveOrUpadet() and even saveOrUpdateCopy() which were deprecated in favor of persist() and merge().

At that time, the persist JPA definition was just a draft, so that particular implementation wasn't reflecting a definitive feature.

Comment: Are you saying that "[Hibernate] only cascades to entities that [are mapped with `cascade="persist"` and] are reachable when you call persist()" is not true anymore in the current version of Hibernate? And, if at some time ago that was actually Hibernate's behavior, how was it implemented (see my comment to JB Nizet)?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I am saying there shouldn't be any difference between jpa and hibernate when it comes to persist.

Comment: The why would it not imply what I said? You say that "For JPA it makes sense to cascade persist()" [even to child entities reachable at flush() time although unreachable at the time of calling persist()].... so that implies Hibernate now behaves the same...